# on click event in append

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm trying to add on click event in a parsexml append but having issues getting it done correctly keeps getting console errors. Maybe I'm doing something wrong in the code but not sure how I should do it. Basically I'm trying to get click events in google analytics using datalayer. this is the code

```
function parseXml(xml)
 {
    $("#main").html("<div class='section group' id='content' data- 
     role='listview' data-inset='true'></div>");
     $(xml).find("item").slice(0, 2).each(function()
    {
    $("#content").append("<a onclick="
      dataLayer.push({
     'event': 'myTrackEvent',
     'eventCategory': 'clicked',
     'eventAction': 'click',
     'eventLabel': 'article click'
     });"class='articleClick' target='_blank' 
     href='"+$(this).find("link").text()+"'><div class='col span_1_of_2'> 
   <div class='thumbnail'><img 
src='"+$(this).find("enclosure").attr('url') 
+"'/></div><div class='text-box'><h2>"+$(this).find("title").text()+" 
   </h2><p>"+$(this).find("description").text()+"</p></div></div> 
   </a>");
      });  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid here:

```
$("#content").append("<a onclick="
  dataLayer.push({
```

`.append()` expects you to finish the string

```
$("#content").append("<a onclick="  dataLayer.push({..    // that is what javascript sees
```

what you need to do is append the string:

```
$("#content").append("<a onclick=" +
  dataLayer.push({
```

or

```
$("#content").append("<a onclick=")
             .append(dataLayer.push({...}));
```

Comment: so it becomes like this? 

$("#content").append("<a onclick="+dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'myTrackEvent','eventCategory': 'clicked','eventAction': 'click','eventLabel': 'article click' }) + " target='_blank' href='"+$(this).find("link").text()+"'><div class='col span_1_of_2'><div class='thumbnail'><img src='"+$(this).find("enclosure").attr('url') +"'/></div><div class='text-box'><h2>"+$(this).find("title").text()+"</h2><p>"+$(this).find("description").text()+"</p></div></div></a>");

Comment: You need to make sure that whatever you append to the string, it should output a valid HTML syntax. It should complete the HTML tag `<a onclick="some_function()" class="some_class">some_text</a>`

Comment: In my answer, I assumed that `dataLayer.push({..etc..})` will complete the HTML tag for the link. And to do that, you need to properly append to the string started the line before. @JosephZammit

Comment: Not sure if i understand what you are saying the code looks like it is complete with the closing tags but for some reason it is not working. is that the correct method to do this or there is another method?

Comment: First, you need to make sure what value is returned by `dataLayer.push()` function. Does it return string? if yes, then you need to properly attach the return value with the `<a onclick="`. If not, then you need to fix your code to complete the HTML link tag @JosephZammit